# Keycloak: Difference between Authentication sessions and User Sessions

Tags: authentication, cache, session, keycloak

I was going through the documentation

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#cache

Here they have described different types of caches.

I didn't quite understand the definitions they provided for Authentication sessions and User Sessions.

For Authentication Session, it says

> "Requests from this cache usually involve only a browser and the
> Keycloak server, not the application."

What type of requests does it mean and what is the application here?

Similarly, for User sessions, it says

> The caches must handle the HTTP requests from the end-user and from
> the application.

Can anyone please provide exactly what they're trying to convey here?

What type of data are they storing? How are they different from each other?